# Как отлаживаться без Eclipse?

Tags: android-sdk, android, ubuntu

Имеется Ubuntu, Android SDK, Oracle Java.

Answer (score 3):

На примере SkeletonApp.

1. Добавить в onCreate вызов

   `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`
2. Добавить в файл настроек ~/.bashrc точку останова

   `stop in com.example.android.skeletonapp.onCreate`
3. Запустить эмулятор

   `emulator -avd test`
4. Установить приложение

   `adb install SkeletonActivity-debug.apk`
5. Запустить Dalvik Debug Monitor

   `ddms`
6. Запустить отладчик (порт виден в ddms)

   `jdb -sourcepath . -attach localhost:8700`

Comment: Операционку укажите

Comment: Это Ubuntu.